# In a bash script, how can I tell if the script output is redirected to a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a shell script that will use colored output when output is terminal, and normal output when redirected to a file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simple:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
    echo "Hello, terminal."
else
    echo "Not a terminal."
fi
```

`-t` tests if the given file descriptor (here, 1 = stdout) is attached to a terminal.

Comment: This doesn't cover the coloring side of the question, for which infomation can be found here: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting